# How to get a Private IP of Edge node using ARM template or Ambari API in Azure

Tags: azure, ambari, azure-rm-template

How to get a Private IP of Edge node using ARM template and Ambari API?

I am installing Edge node using following edgenode part of ARM template. I want to get Private IP Edge node for my custom application. How can I get it using ARM template or using Ambari by using edgenodeName?

```
{
  'name': '[concat(parameters('clusterName'),'/', parameters('edgenodeName'))]',
  'type': 'Microsoft.HDInsight/clusters/applications',
  'apiVersion': '2015-03-01-preview',
    'dependsOn': [
        '[concat('Microsoft.HDInsight/clusters/', parameters('clusterName'))]'
    ],
    'properties': {
    'marketPlaceIdentifier': 'EmptyEdgeNode',
    'computeProfile': {
      'roles': [{
        'name': 'edgenode',
        'targetInstanceCount': 1,
        'hardwareProfile': {
          'vmSize': '[parameters('edgenodeSize')]'
        }
      }]
    },
    'installScriptActions': [],
    'uninstallScriptActions': [],
    'httpsEndpoints': [],
    'applicationType': 'CustomApplication'
  }
}
```

**Update 1:-**

Here is my json representation from resources.azure.com

```
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.HDInsight/clusters/$clusterName",
  "name": "$clusterName",
  "type": "Microsoft.HDInsight/clusters",
  "location": "Central US",
  "etag": "33908087-88d4-43e6-bad4-7668bb90fa39",
  "tags": null,
  "properties": {
    "clusterVersion": "3.5.1000.0",
    "osType": "Linux",
    "clusterDefinition": {
      "blueprint": "https://blueprints.azurehdinsight.net/spark-3.5.1000.0.9988582.json",
      "kind": "SPARK",
      "componentVersion": {
        "Spark": "1.6"
      }
    },
    "computeProfile": {
      "roles": [
        {
          "name": "headnode",
          "targetInstanceCount": 2,
          "hardwareProfile": {
            "vmSize": "Standard_D12_V2"
          },
          "osProfile": {
            "linuxOperatingSystemProfile": {
              "username": "$userName"
            }
          },
          "virtualNetworkProfile": {
            "id": "/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/$vnetName",
            "subnet": "/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/$vnetName/subnets/default"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "workernode",
          "targetInstanceCount": 1,
          "hardwareProfile": {
            "vmSize": "Standard_D12_V2"
          },
          "osProfile": {
            "linuxOperatingSystemProfile": {
              "username": "$userName"
            }
          },
          "virtualNetworkProfile": {
            "id": "/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/$vnetName",
            "subnet": "/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/$vnetName/subnets/default"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "zookeepernode",
          "targetInstanceCount": 3,
          "hardwareProfile": {
            "vmSize": "Medium"
          },
          "osProfile": {
            "linuxOperatingSystemProfile": {
              "username": "$userName"
            }
          },
          "virtualNetworkProfile": {
            "id": "/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/$vnetName",
            "subnet": "/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/$vnetName/subnets/default"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "edgenode1",
          "targetInstanceCount": 1,
          "hardwareProfile": {
            "vmSize": "Standard_D3_v2"
          },
          "osProfile": {
            "linuxOperatingSystemProfile": {
              "username": "$userName"
            }
          },
          "virtualNetworkProfile": {
            "id": "/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/$vnetName",
            "subnet": "/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/$vnetName/subnets/default"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
    "clusterState": "Running",
    "createdDate": "2017-04-26T07:44:54.4",
    "quotaInfo": {
      "coresUsed": 16
    },
    "connectivityEndpoints": [
      {
        "name": "SSH",
        "protocol": "TCP",
        "location": "$clusterName-ssh.azurehdinsight.net",
        "port": 22
      },
      {
        "name": "HTTPS",
        "protocol": "TCP",
        "location": "$clusterName.azurehdinsight.net",
        "port": 443
      }
    ],
    "tier": "standard"
  }
}
```

Comment: cab you paste the cluster json representation? go to resources.azure.com and navigate to the cluster, and paste the json into the question

Comment: @4c74356b41 I don't have the cluster right now. I need to create a cluster. Right now I have an ARM template only

Comment: good luck with that ;)

Comment: @4c74356b41 Can I update ARM template in question? Is it enough for you?

Comment: well, I can't help you unless you show me the object that gets created. If its the same as HDinsight cluster there won't be any data about particular nodes, so unless you can extract data from the node itself (I'm talking about ARM reference function) and i'm not sure that's possible using ARM since I've never seen node objects in, say, vmss, you are out of luck

Comment: @4c74356b41 I have created cluster and update json representation in question.

Comment: so is `connectivity endpoint` the data that you need?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142703/discussion-between-karan-and-4c74356b41).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Ambari API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-manage-ambari-rest-api) to get Edge node IP. When your template deploy succeed, you could the following script to list edge node IP.

```
#!/bin/bash
PASSWORD=$1
CLUSTERNAME=$2
###list all host private IP
for HOSTNAME in $(curl -u admin:$PASSWORD -sS -G "https://$CLUSTERNAME.azurehdinsight.net/api/v1/clusters/$CLUSTERNAME/hosts" | jq -r '.items[].Hosts.host_name')
do
    IP=$(curl -u admin:$PASSWORD -sS -G "https://$CLUSTERNAME.azurehdinsight.net/api/v1/clusters/$CLUSTERNAME/hosts/$HOSTNAME" | jq -r '.Hosts.ip')
  echo "$HOSTNAME <--> $IP" >>host.txt
done
cat host.txt |grep '^ed'|awk -F\> '{print $2 }'
```

In `host.txt`, you will get all host IP such like this.

```
ed11-******.gx.internal.cloudapp.net <--> 10.4.0.4
ed20-******.gx.internal.cloudapp.net <--> 10.4.0.8
hn0-******.gx.internal.cloudapp.net <--> 10.4.0.18
hn1-******.gx.internal.cloudapp.net <--> 10.4.0.13
wn0-******.gx.internal.cloudapp.net <--> 10.4.0.7
zk1-******.gx.internal.cloudapp.net <--> 10.4.0.12
zk3-******.gx.internal.cloudapp.net <--> 10.4.0.9
zk5-******.gx.internal.cloudapp.net <--> 10.4.0.10
```

You could execute the script like below:

```
[root@shui home]# ./deploy.sh <password> <clustername>
 10.4.0.4
 10.4.0.8
```